# Read JSON Tree structure in Scala Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to process an Ajax POST request in Play Framework 2.1.3. The post data is a JSON object and has a tree structure like:

```
{ id: "a", name: "myname", kids : [{ id: "a1", name : "kid1", kids: []}, {id: "a2", name: "kid2", kids: [{id: "aa1", name :"grandkid", kids: []}]}]
```

I would like to nest the 'children' arbitrarily deep. The class I would have in mind is like this (I realize the recursiveness can be problematic):

```
case class Person {
  id: String,
  name: String,
  kids: Array[Person]
}
```

The format I would have in mind:

```
implicit val personFormat:Format[Person] = Json.format[Person]
```

Play is throwing errors on my Format that I wrote:

type mismatch; found : controllers.Resources.Person required: Array[controllers.Resources.Person]

I am aware that Play has a Tree structure. I couldn't find examples/documentation on how to tie that to JSON reads.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need a recursive val, something like:

```
implicit val jsonReads: Reads[Person] = ((__ \ "id").read[String] and (__ \ "name").read[String] and (__ \ "kids").read[Seq[Person]])(apply _)
```

(I've changed the collection type from Array to Seq because it's more general and allows you to change your implementation without affecting downline code.)

This is using the syntax documented [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJsonCombinators).

Comment: Thanks Robin, I am trying to incorporate your answer and I get a compile error 'not found: value apply'. Am I missing something basic? And Does 'kids' in the Person class need to be 'Seq[Person]' for your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I guess you are not declaring it in the companion object then. So just change `apply` to `Person`. You could change it to `Array` but I'm not sure if Play can automatically read `Array`s; that's why I suggested changing the collection type used in `Person` from `Array` to `Seq`. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I see this working is using either JsArray or Array[String] instead of Array[Person] in your Person case class.  The JSON Macro Inception can only generate reads + writes code for primitives and lists, maps, and arrays for objects for which there already exist implicit JSON read + write code.  Essentially you can't have a case class that references itself.

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json._

case class Person(
  id   : String,
  name : String,
  kids : JsArray
)

object Person extends ((String,String,JsArray) => Person) {

  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Person]

}
```

Comment: That isn't good design though; that is exposing the wire representation; what if you decide to also accept XML?

Comment: The question was how to read a JSON structure, XML is irrelevant.

Comment: I am talking about a potential future design decision. But even regardless of that, you should not expose the wire representation in your case classes - it forces the client code to be concerned about deserialization, which it should not have to worry about.

Comment: Jason (and Robin), thanks a lot for helping me out on this! Both solutions work like a charm and help me understand Play/Scala better.  Thanks!